# OnClick open Activity1 but send EXTRA_TEXT to Activity10...Is a String necessary or can I simply use intent? Can post XML if helpful

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, onclick

Multiple Activity App...Activity1 (SiteData) collects data and sends to Activity10 (DataReview)...but before going straight to Activity10 user must go through Activities2-9 (SanDiegoArea, etc...) collecting data and also passing EXTRA_TEXT to the other activity until Activity10...

This way:
(Activity1 -> Activity2 -> ... -> Activity10)

Activity10 will be able to review Activity1-9 EXTRA_TEXT for verification...Code is as follows but I'm getting no EXTRA_TEXT at Activity10 to display in it's TextViews for review? How can I solve the problem?

**Activity1 - SITEDATA - data info input**

```java
public class SiteData extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "MultipleActivities.EXTRA_TEXT";
    public static final String EXTRA_NUMBER = "MultipleActivities.EXTRA_NUMBER";


        public void clickFunction(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SanDiegoArea.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Log.i("Info", "Login Details Entered");
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sitedata);

        //Possible coding needed for Autocomplete...see more

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSanDiegoArea();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openSanDiegoArea() {

            EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            String text = editText1.getText().toString();

            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataReview.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, number);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**ACTIVITY10 - DATAREVIEW Section getting info**

```java
public class DataReview extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThankYou.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Log.i("Info", "Sample Data Sent to BWTF");
    }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.datareview);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String text = intent.getStringExtra(SiteData.EXTRA_TEXT);
            int number = intent.getIntExtra(SiteData.EXTRA_NUMBER, 0);

            TextView textView1  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            TextView textView2  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
            TextView textView3  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
            TextView textView4  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
            TextView textView5  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextTime);

            textView1.setText(text);
            textView2.setText("" + number);

    }
};
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit confuse. Please clarify it. See if I was able to understood your problem: You have ten activities and one will be called after the other (Activity1 -> Activity2 -> ...-> Activity10). In each activity the user will enter data and you whant to get all the collected data in the last activity the Activity10. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Exactly...Most of the activities are ListView clickable items but each activity once selcted should send EXTRA_TEXT or chosen data to last Activity10

Comment: I've edited your question in order for it to be more easily understood. It will enter in a queue for approval but in the meantime I will try to answer it to you.

Comment: Actually Activity1 is data input, Activity2-8 are Listview selection options and Activity9 is DataReview ready to send via email. So really the answer is no I can't just intent send input from Activity1 to Activity10 as well as then go from Activity1 to Activity2....Haven't gotten to fragments just yet in course but will learn asap! Ya I'm new so my positive feedback to you won't be seen either...Doing an APP for a non-profit while learning and just need to hook this back end programming up to work - Thanks for advice!

Comment: If you think that my answer solved your doubts, please consider accepting it otherwise if you still have any doubts, just ask it and I will see if I can help!

Comment: As I said b/c I'm new it doesn't accept my feedback...thanks for help but looks as if more coding to get this enabled and functional!

Comment: Even been new you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. In fact if the question is yours, only You can do it. But you don't have to do it if you don't want it to. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Activity1 calls Activity2, it will have to pass data to it the way you are doing. ( I'm guessing here that your Activity2 is DataReview.class)
But Activity2 will call Activity3 and, in order for it not to loose the data received from activity 2 you will have to send it too. In other words, Activity1 sends Activity1's data to Activity2, Activity2 sends Activity1's and Activity2's data to Activity3 and so on.
In this way, Activity9 will receive (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) data from it's caller Activity8 and will have to pass all this accumulated data to Activity10.

Considering that Activity3 is called by Activity2 it can't see the data sent from Activity1 because it don't know it unless Activity2 pass it too. Am I been clear?

If you are just learning Android it is ok to do it this way in order to learn but it is not the better way to solve this problem. I would use a same [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) on all activities in order to represent this data in order to always have just one place for holding it as it would make my code more clear. In reality I wouldn't even use all those Activities, I would use only one activity and work with 10 [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments), one for each page ([it is just to provide navigation between then](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)). So those are Ideas for you to improve your app if you feel It would be good.